# Is there a way to optimize this nested for loop working with 100k rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

would you like to enlighten my mind  and help me how to optimize this nested for loop?

I am having two dataframe the second one is the competitor to the first one.

`df_competitor would look like this`

```
    price   units 
0   12  120
1   42  1256
2   65  176
```

and the `df` output like this

```
 code   name    min_price   max_units
  0 ee21    rwqrw   12      120 
  1 qw1256  tytyu   12      120
  2 gbv176  qqww    42      1256
```

the for loop

```
for i, num in enumerate(competitor_indexes):
            for n in num:
     
                    df.loc[i, 'minimum_price'] = min(
                        df.loc[i, 'minimum_price'], df_competitor .loc[n, 'price'])
                    df.loc[i, 'maximum_units'] = max(
                        df.loc[i, 'maximum_units'], df_competitor .loc[n, 'units'])
```

The **competitor_indexes** is just the index of the row that should be taken in account.
For example

```
 [
[0,2]
[1,4]
[0,3]

]
```

It has exactly the same amount of rows that the `df` has

I just want to calculate the minimum price and maximum units

It is very slow when talking about 100k+ rows , how do I optimize this please?

Comment: Add the input dataframes please

Comment: also please share a target output so we can understand your question

Comment: i've tried to add there some clarity I am afraid this wont be enough as well let me know

Comment: What does `df` look like *before* the loop runs?